# Reference conditions for balances on nonreactive processes

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

In one of the examples in my book (Elementary Priniciples of Chemical Processes) where I am asked to calculate the rate of heat input required to heat a stream of methane and air from 20°C to 300°C, two references conditions are chosen (see picture).

In the text below the box it says "The reference condition for methane was chosen so that $H_{in}$ could be set equal to zero, and that for air was chosen so that $H_{in}$ and $H_{out}$ could be determined from Table B.8."

Why isn't it that $H_{in}$ for air is set equal to zero since the specific enthaply for air at 25°C and 1 atm is 0? How did they get that $H_{in}$ for methane should be zero?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd start by looking at Table B8. What does it provide as a value for H of air?

Comment: I've added a picture of Table B8

Comment: It seems you are right. I share your confusion. Not sure why H is set to 0.

Comment: As long as there is no chemical reaction, you can use a different reference temperature for every species in the mixture.  Mathematically, it will still work out OK.